# Dealing with Masked Columns in Redshift: How to Load Data from One Table to Another?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I'm currently having an issue in **Redshift**(plpgsql) dwh with loading data let's say from table 'source' to 'target' with same structure having columns col1,col2,col3 where col2 in table source is attached with **masking policy**. So when I start loading the data from source to target with simple insert or merge query the col2 data from source table is being loaded with actual masked string value instead of actual value.

I'm new to redshift, could someone help with solution as to how to load data from one table to another when source table columns are masked?